# jQuery help: trying to set placeholder values for input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, here's my jQuery code:

```
 if($('#quotation_request_payment_option_lease').is(':checked')){
    $('#quotation_request_down_payment').attr('placeholder', "1300");
  }

 else if($('#quotation_request_payment_option_finance').is(':checked'))
  {
    $('#quotation_request_down_payment').attr('placeholder', "1500");
  }
```

If the quotation_request_payment_option_lease checkbox is checked, then I want to set the placeholder in the quotation_request_down_payment input field to 1300.

And if the quotation_request_payment_option_finance checkbox is checked, then I want to set the placeholder in the quotation_request_down_payment input field to 1500.

Right now, the default for the page is that the quotation_request_payment_option_lease checkbox is checked, so when I load the page, the placeholder for the quoation_request_down_payment input field is set to 1300 (which is what I want).

The problem I'm having is that when I check the quotation_request_payment_option_finance checkbox (note: it's set so that only one of the two checkboxes can be checked at once), the placeholder remains 1300, it doesn't change to 1500.

Can anyone think of a way to fix this?

Comment: Simply put, if you want to change something when the user changes something, you need an event handler, in your case you need to listen for the `change` event on the checkbox, and change the placeholders accordingly.

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question?

Answer (score 0):

You must do these validations within an event, like [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

> Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

*You can do this without a class(`.ckbox`), with the selector `$("input[type='checkbox']")`

```js
$(".ckbox").change(function() {
  if ($('#quotation_request_payment_option_lease').is(':checked')) {
    $('#quotation_request_down_payment').attr('placeholder', "1300");
  } else if ($('#quotation_request_payment_option_finance').is(':checked')) {
    $('#quotation_request_down_payment').attr('placeholder', "1500");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="quotation_request_payment_option_lease" class="ckbox"><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="quotation_request_payment_option_finance" class="ckbox">
<br>
<input type="text" id="quotation_request_down_payment" placeholder="default">
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have handle the onclick so that you can initiate the check you want to perform.
Something like this.
Add a class to both checkbox, and then add click listener of that class.

```
$('check_box_class').on('click', function(){
      if($('#quotation_request_payment_option_lease').is(':checked')) {
          $('#quotation_request_down_payment').attr('placeholder', "1300");
      }else if($('#quotation_request_payment_option_finance').is(':checked')) {
          $('#quotation_request_down_payment').attr('placeholder', "1500");
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> (note: it's set so that only one of the two checkboxes can be checked
>   at once)

Substitute `<input type="radio">` elements for `<input type="checkbox">` elements with each having `name` attribute set to "quotation_request_down_payment"
. Set `class` attribute of two `<input type="text">` elements to `"quotation_request_down_payment"` at `html` instead of single element having `id`. Toggle the `display` of the `<input type="text">` elements' from `inline-block` to `none` utilizing `css` `:checked`, adjacent sibling selector `+` and  `:not()`.

```css
#quotation_request_payment_option_lease:checked
+ input + input {
  display: inline-block;
}

#quotation_request_payment_option_lease:not(:checked)
+ input + input,
#quotation_request_payment_option_lease:checked
+ input + input + input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" 
         id="quotation_request_payment_option_lease" 
         name="quotation_request_payment_option" 
         value="finance" checked>
  <input type="radio"  
         id="quotation_request_payment_option_finance" 
         name="quotation_request_payment_option"
         value="finance">
  <input type="text" 
         name="quotation_request_payment_option_lease"
         placeholder="1300" 
         class="quotation_request_down_payment"
         value="1300">
  <input type="text" 
         name="quotation_request_payment_option_finance"
         placeholder="1500" 
         class="quotation_request_down_payment"
         value="1500">
</form>
```